# Browser cached previous Flask project

Tags: python, flask

I have one Flask project on my PC and now I would like to setup another one, so I just created a .py file, copied the hello world sample code and ran it. Then I opened `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` in my browser to test the new app, but unfortunately the browser loaded my other project (the first one). It seems it has been cached somehow, because I'm getting the same results from Chrome and Firefox too. (The apps are in different folders with different file names)

I assume it's a trivial thing, but I would really appreciate if somebody could tell me how could solve the conflict between the two apps (if that's the problem) or how can I clean the cache.

You can see below that I'm using a basic setup and it runs without any errors so I have no idea what can cause the issue.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: browsers do not cache Python projects (or any other backend files). have you stopped your project before running new one?

Comment: I didn't cancel the build in Sublime Text, so that's the problem? How can I check it and stop it if it runs? @sobolevn

Comment: Use `app.run(port=5001)` and connect to `http://127.0.0.1:5001`. I am suspicious that you are calling `python app.py` from the wrong place. Use `pwd` in your terminal to check you're in the correct directory. Also maybe you are editing the wrong file in sublime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your browsing data in chrome with "Cached images and files" checked if you think this is the problem.

I wouldn't expect this to happen unless the other project was still running, but then you would not be able to bind both apps to the same port. Are you sure you are running the right script?

Try `app.run(port=5001)` and connect to localhost:5001.

Comment: It's working perfectly with the new port. Do you think it doesn't works on the other port because the other one is still running on that url?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to run two applications both trying to bind to port 5000. Try `ps aux | grep 'python'` and see if you can find the process for the other application. Use `kill <PID>` if you find it.

Comment: Also try `netstat -lntp`, find the process and kill it.